# Server IP Address in Drupal PHP Status

Tags: 6, log-messages

How does one get the server IP address of the server you are on to appear at http://examplehost.com/admin/reports/status/php -- at the very bottom ? I keep getting 127.0.0.1. This is on two web servers that are behind a load balancer.

Comment: You balancer is probably configured to not pass the original IP along to the web server.

Comment: I am not looking for the original or client IP. I am looking for the IP of the server that executed the php script (_:

Comment: Ops, sorry about that. :) Seems I did the same mistake as Johnathan Elmore below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The admin/reports/status/php is actually the output of [phpinfo()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) and it simply shows your PHP configuration summary.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202872/php-serverserver-addr-variable-always-returns-127-0-0-1
suggests using this code to get the real IP:

```
getHostByName(php_uname('n'));
```